# Editting ForeignKey from "child" table

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-forms

I'm programming on py with django. I have models:

`class Product(mymodels.Base):
    title = models.CharField()
    price = models.ForeignKey(Price)
    promoPrice = models.ForeignKey(Price, related_name="promo_price")`

class Price(mymodels.Base):
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=3)
    taxValue = models.DecimalField("Tax Value", max_digits=10, decimal_places=3)
    valueWithTax = models.DecimalField("Value with Tax", max_digits=10, decimal_places=3)

I want to see INPUTs for both prices when editing product, but cannot find any possibility to do that.
inlines = [...] works only from Price to Product, which is stupid in this case.

Thanx for adnvance.

Comment: I think you need make your own form and tell to admin use it.

Comment: I think you should reconsider your models. Price doesn't seem like it should be it's own model. I would have price and promoPrice be numerical fields and then have taxValue and valueWithTax be properties of the Product class

Answer (score 0):

How about using this instead?

```
class Product(mymodels.Base):
    title = models.CharField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=3)
    tax = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=3)
    promo_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=3)
    promo_tax = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=3)

    def price_with_tax(self):
        return self.price + self.tax

    def promo_price_with_tax(self):\
        return self.promo_price + self.promo_tax\
```

(P.S. tax and promo_tax might be good candidates to be ForeignKeys to TaxRate models)